# Height in percentage not working

Tags: html, css

as you can see on this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/yLrC8/, I tried to set a height of 70% for my Article DIV  in order to have the height of the DIV always equal to 70% of the user browser size (but with a min height of 400px) but for some rason it's not working. Would you know why? Thanks

```
<div class="menu">
      <div class="inner"> <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com/index.html" class="logo">Gregory</a>
    <ul>
          <li > <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com">Category 1</a> </li>
          <li > <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com">Category 2</a> </li>
          <li > <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com">Category 3</a> </li>
          <li > <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com">Category 4</a> </li>
          <li > <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com">Category 5</a> </li>
          <li class="selected"> <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com/">Category 6</a> </li>
          <li > <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com">Contact</a> <span class="pipe"></span> </li>
        </ul>
    <div class="social">
          <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.123.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
        </div>
  </div>
    </div>
<div id="quote">
      <blockquote>
    <p>"Nos soutenons depuis la début"</p>
    <cite>Innovation</cite> </blockquote>
      <blockquote>
    <p>"Qualité exceptionnelle"</p>
    <cite>Feologiste</cite> </blockquote>
    </div>

<div class="news">

</div>
<div class="linksicons"> sds </div>
<div class="article content">
  <h1>Biography</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_b.jpg" title="Caption. Can be aligned it to any side.">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_s.jpg" width="75" height="75">
</a><h2>Sub-title</h2><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
    <p><strong>LOREM IPSUM</strong></p>
          <h3>Tel. +123 456.789 - E-mail: contact@kjhhklh.com</h3>
  </div>


    </div>

<div class="footer">
<a href="#_" class="lien_hot_news">Prochains événements</a>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Reset
/* -------------------------------------------- */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
b, strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
em {
    font-style: italic;
}
/* Font family reference
/* -------------------------------------------- */

/*

font-family:'FuturaW01-LightOblique';
font-family:'Futura W01 Book';
font-family:'Futura W01 Book Oblique';
font-family:'Futura W01 Medium';
font-family:'Futura W01 Heavy';
font-family:'Futura W01 Bold';

*/


/* Global
/* -------------------------------------------- */

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width:950px;

}
body {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Book', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.285714286; /* 18px */
    color: #2b2b2b;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../images/biographie.jpg);
    top: 0;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
a {
    outline: none;
    color: #2b2b2b;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li a, .footer li a {
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Heavy', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: 0.10em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ecb825;
}
.menu li a:hover, .menu li.selected a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
/* Fade border under links on hover */
.csstransitions .menu a, .csstransitions .footer a {
    -webkit-transition: border, color 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: border, color 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: border, color 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: border, color 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: border, color 0.2s ease-out;
}
p a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ECB825;
}
p a:hover {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
h1, h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Heavy', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding-top:5px;
}
h2 {
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Heavy', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding-top:5px;
}
h3 {
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Heavy', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
p {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 1.25em;
}
strong, b {
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Heavy', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
/* Navigation
/* -------------------------------------------- */
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 768px;
    max-width: 1950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 65px;
    z-index: 310;
    color: #2b2b2b;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('../images/shadow-menu.png');
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.menu .inner {
    height: 65px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu .logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 81px;
    top: 19px;
}
.menu ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 18px auto 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 200px;
}
.menu li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.menu li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.menu li a {
    float: left;
}
.menu .pipe {
    width: 1px;
    float: left;
    height: 33px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    background: url('../images/pipe.gif') 100% 0 repeat-y;
}
/* Search */
.social {
    position: absolute;
    right: 61px;
    top: 23px;
    text-align: right;
}

/*News box xml driven */

.linksicons
{
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left:35px;   
    position: relative;
    z-index: 95;
    margin-bottom: 90px;
    background: #0F3;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    /* max-width: 25%; */

    overflow-y: scroll!important;
}



/* Article - white bg */
.twocolumns {
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-count: 2;
}
.article {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
    text-align:justify;
    width: 450px;
    min-height:400px;
    height: 70%;
    padding: 50px 32px 49px 62px;
    margin-right:75px;  
    position: relative;
    z-index: 15;
    margin-top: 90px;
    background: #ccc;
    /* max-width: 25%; */

    overflow-y: scroll!important;
}

.article p {
    padding-right:20px;
}
.article h1, .article h2 {
    margin-top: -4px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
/* Article - no bg, large text */
.article-full {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 84px 0 49px 0;
    background: none;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
.article-full p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 56px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Light', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 82px;
}
.article-full p strong {
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Heavy', Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* Footer
/* -------------------------------------------- */
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 300;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 768px;
    max-width: 1950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #cfc8c0;
    height: 40px;
}

.lien_hot_news {
    background: #e14242;
    color: #fff;
    font: italic normal 18px Georgia, serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    height: 38px;
    width: 270px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.footer a {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom-color: #2b2b2b;
}
.footer a:hover {
    border-bottom-color: #ECB825;
}

/* Quovolver Demo Styles */

/*
 |  All required styles for the effect
 |  are labeled with this *required*
*/

#quote {
    left: 2%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 335px;
    z-index: 2;
}
blockquote p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Book', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    /* color:  #0A4672; */
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
}
blockquote cite {
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Book', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
/*
 |  Setting the width for the blockquotes is required
 |  to accurately adjust it's contianer
*/

blockquote {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 430px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
/*
 |  The #quote_wrap div is created
 |  by Quovolver to wrap the quotes
*/

#quote_wrap {
    margin: 40px 0;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Heights given as a percentage only work if the parent element has an explicit height set as well – if it just has `height:auto`, then it can not work.

Comment: @CBroe is right. You'll need to use Javascript to achieve this, binding to the window's resize event.

Comment: You're setting `height: 100%` in the `html, body` selector, but then you're overriding it with `height: auto` in the `body` selector.

Comment: @MattCoughlin well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
.article {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:justify;
    width: 450px;
    min-height:400px;
    height:70%;
    right:0;
    padding: 50px 32px 49px 62px;
    margin-right:75px;
    z-index: 15;
    margin-top: 90px;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

with positioning the `article` absolute you can also exactly define where you want it to be (e.g. how far form top and how far form bottom of its scope) and instead of the float I set now `right:0;`. Now you just need to make sue the right (the one you want) parental container is set to `position:relative;` with a certain height so you use 70% of the one you want.

If you want the window/viewport to bi its scope, you have to position it `fixed`.